# Facebook App links using Mobile Hosted API

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios7.1

I have implemented Facebook App Links by following steps mentioned with Mobile Hosted API for the iOS app which is in Appstore.

When I test the App Link (`http://fb.me/....`) in browser or mobile, it doesn't redirect to Appstore.

However, I have tried it for some other App & it is getting redirected.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't want others go through lot of R&D as I did. I am posting the answer myself.

As our App was available only for Indian stores, the Facebook App Link was not working.

When I changed the territory to worldwide & tested the App Link, it works. I observed that whatever Facebook link is given indirectly redirects to 'us' store.